How would you take the derivative of an integral in this case? (Gateaux derivative)
Let's say $g(x)$ is a real valued function.
$$\int_a^b q(g(x)) d F(g(x),r)$$
$F(g(x),r)$ is a function that maps $(g(x),r)$ to a real number.
What is the derivative of this expression with regards to $g(x)$?. The part I don't understand is how to deal with $dF(g(x),r)$ and its derivative. I know what a Gateaux differential is, but still don't know how to deal with this.

It can be very helpful to rewrite your integral as a Riemann-like sum, expand $dF(g(x),r)$ to $F(g(x_i+\Delta x_i),r) - F(g(x_i),r)$, then differentiate with respect to $g(x)$ (now that $F$ isn't wearing its "measure mask").
